# How do I use LINQ with GROUP BY and multiple MAX(...) to select multiple fields?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I need to select fields from unique records within a table with multiple where clauses. I currently am using C# and LINQ fluent syntax connected with NHibernate.  So I am wondering if there is a way to create this query that way. Here is a test dataset:

```
+----+----------+------+------+
| Id | ParentId | Name | Type |
+----+----------+------+------+
|  1 |      100 | A    |    1 |
|  2 |      100 | A    |    2 |
|  3 |      100 | A    |    3 |
|  4 |      200 | B    |    1 |
|  5 |      300 | A    |    1 |
|  6 |      300 | A    |    2 |
|  7 |      400 | A    |    1 |
|  8 |      400 | A    |    2 |
|  9 |      400 | A    |    3 |
| 10 |      400 | A    |    4 |
+----+----------+------+------+
```

I can get the results I want using this SQL query:

```
SELECT ParentId, COUNT(Name) as Cnt, Max(Id) as  Id, Max(Name) as Name, Max(Type) as Type FROM TestGroupBy Where Name = 'A' Group By ParentId;
```

This gives the result:

```
+----------+-----+----+------+------+
| ParentId | Cnt | Id | Name | Type |
+----------+-----+----+------+------+
|      100 |   3 |  3 | A    |    3 |
|      300 |   2 |  6 | A    |    2 |
|      400 |   4 | 10 | A    |    4 |
+----------+-----+----+------+------+
```

I know how to make the group by query but I can't figure out how to do the multiple MAX selects.  Is that just not possible with LINQ?  If it's not, then what would be a way that I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a queryable, you can call `Select` and pass a predicate. The `new` keyword constructs an object with the schema you prefer.

```
.Select( x => new
{
    ParentId = x.ParentId
    Cnt = x.Count(p => p.Name),
    Id = x.Max( p => p.Id  )
    /*etcetera*/
} );
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "having a constructor"?  I tried this but my object does not have Max or Count functions on it.  It's just a POCO.

Comment: @JamesEhly Max and Count are callable from the predicates. The constructor thing at the start of my answer was not well written, I'll edit my answer to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small snippet that shows you the linq query in context:

```
public class Row
{
    public int Id;
    public int ParentId;
    public string Name;
    public int Type;

    public Row(int Id, int ParentId, string Name, int Type)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.ParentId = ParentId;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Type = Type;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Row> test = new List<Row>();
        test.Add(new Row(1, 100, "A", 1));
        test.Add(new Row(2, 100, "A", 2));
        test.Add(new Row(3, 100, "A", 3));
        test.Add(new Row(4, 200, "B", 1));
        test.Add(new Row(5, 300, "A", 1));
        test.Add(new Row(6, 300, "A", 2));
        test.Add(new Row(7, 400, "A", 1));
        test.Add(new Row(8, 400, "A", 2));
        test.Add(new Row(9, 400, "A", 3));
        test.Add(new Row(10, 400, "A", 4));

        dynamic d = from row in test
                    where row.Name.Equals("A")
                    group row by row.ParentId into grp 
                    select new { 
                        ParentId = grp.Key, 
                        Cnt = grp.Count(), 
                        Id = grp.Max(x => x.Id), 
                        Name = grp.Max(x => x.Name), 
                        Type = grp.Max(x => x.Type) 
                    };
    }
}
```